# JavaFX Service/Task/Worker and automation

Tags: java, service, javafx, task, worker

I am using IntelliJ IDEA.
I have a "Clicker game" project that im working on because I want to learn java and practise a bit. The labels in my JavaFX window need to be updated constantly. The way I wanted to do this is through a Timer and TimerTask, but I read somewhere that this wasn't a good idea and that I'd rather use a Worker/Task/Service. Implementing this (calling my Update() method) works once, but results in a runtime error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, anyone that can help me?

The update method:

```
public void Update(){
    dollarlabel.setText(Double.toString(player.getDollars()));
    vaselineCost.setText(Double.toString(player.shop.vaseline.cost));
    bolCost.setText(Double.toString(player.shop.bol.cost));
    appleCost.setText(Double.toString(player.shop.apple.cost));
    duikenCost.setText(Double.toString(player.shop.duiken.cost));
}
```

The service:

```
public Service service = new Service() {
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        Update();
        return null;
    }
};
```

The method that starts the service:

```
public void InitializeService(){
    service.start();
}
```

InitializeService is called on the press of a button. Ideally it is called at the start of the program but hey..one issue at a time right?

here is the error when I call on "InitializeService": http://pastebin.com/jrsVh23R

To clarify, I do not know where the null pointer exception comes from. I declared my variables before they are used i.e.:

```
public Label dollarlabel = new Label();
public Label vaselineCost = new Label();
public Label bolCost = new Label();
public Label duikenCost = new Label();
public Label appleCost = new Label();
```

anyone that knows what im doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be returning something other than null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
protected Task createTask() { 
return new Task<Void>() {
   protected String call() throws        Exception 
  {
       Update();
       return null; 
   }
 }; 
 }
```

Adapted from code fragment in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)

Regarding the start of service...

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
{
  public void handle() 
  {
       // Call to initilaizeService() 
   } 
}) ;
```

For understanding eventhandlers I used this [link](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/)

In the update method add this..

```
void update() 
{
      Platform.runLater (new Runnable () 
      {
            public void run () 
             {
                 //all calls to setText goes here 
            } 
     }) ;
 }
```

Comment: This worked by changing the void to string as well.. The service now succeeds. how do i make it repeat after the state is set to Succeeded? I am not really familiar with eventhandlers yet

Comment: Well I thought you didn't care about the generic type so I posted Void

Comment: Yea that snot the issue, thank you for your solution. the problem is now that once it executes the service state is set to Succeeded, and wont repeat itself.

Comment: Well you have a button and on click call start service.. If you want the code and the site comment I'll edit the answer..

Comment: yea but isnt the idea of a service that its basicly repeating a task over and over again?

Comment: No it is used to do tasks in the background.. I've attached a link.. Visit the link it's given..

Comment: Thanks i've figured it out.. now for some reason it doesnt update the labels but does execute the println statement in put exactly before and after the label updates in the update method...

Comment: I'm just guessing here....  Try calling requestLayout()  on one label for starter after setting the text in service..

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

Any idea?

Comment: Yup that's what I was looking for... Any changes made to any of the fx components must be done in a fx thread.. I'll post a code wait..

Comment: dude you're a boss.. not kidding thanks for all your help

Comment: Happy to help... If the answer is what you were looking for Mark as correct so others are benefitted.. Any more problems? always there to help buddy..